# How can i access address of an instruction mentioned in shared library from a file using the library?

Tags: c, linux, caching, assembly, shared-libraries

I have created a shared library named libSum.so and two c file name file1.c and file2.c  and using the libsum in both the c files.
There is a 'sum' function  inside libsum.so which is doing addition operation. using debugger i got the address of assembly instruction of sum function .Now i want to read this address from my  c code.
How can i access this address?

Answer (score 2):

If the function has external linkage and is public to the library, using the name of the function in an expression will result in the address of the function.

If the function has external linkage but is private to the library, you could attempt to add your own object to the library, and your code would return the address of the library function.

If the function is static, there is no standard way, unless the function address happens to get stored in an externally visible variable. Some various hackish ways:

- If you need to call the function, you can just create your implementation. If the source of the file is available to you, and the license of the software allows for it, you can simply create a new library that consists only of that function.
- If you are willing to recompile the original library itself, you can define a function that has external linkage that can return the address of the function for you.
- If you can induce a signal (e.g., a floating point exception or a segmentation fault) while the function is being called, you can attempt to capture the address of the function by scanning backwards through the call stack from within a signal handler.

---

The above suggestions assume that your program has linked with the library. If your program intends to invoke the function from the library that has not been linked to your program, then you might be asking about dynamic linking. Again, the function needs to have external linkage and be public to the library. As long as that is true, on POSIX systems (which Linux is), you can invoke `dlopen` to open the shared library, and `dlsym` to resolve the address of a public symbol within the library.

```
void *handle = dlopen("libSum.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void *sym = dlsym(handle, "sum");
void (*sum)();
_Static_assert(sizeof sym == sizeof sum);
memcpy(&sum, &sym, sizeof(sum));
```

Comment: *using the name of the function in an expression will result in the address of the function.*  In C yes; the compiler will get the address from the GOT, typically doing that instead of taking the address of a PLT stub or something.  (In assembly you'd have to do that yourself, and this question is tagged assembly as well.  Your best bet is to look at compiler output for your platform.  Anyway, doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking about, but relevant to the question title + tags.)